# Parsing PDF removing month

Tags: ruby, pdf, pdf-reader

I'm parsing a pdf that has some dates by splitting the lines and then searching them. The following are example lines:

```
Posted Date: 02/11/2015
Effective Date: 02/05/2015
```

When I find `Posted Date`, I split on the `:` and pull out `02/11/2015`. But when I do the same for `effective date`, it only returns `/05/2015`.  When I write all lines, it displays that date as `/05/2015` while the PDF has the `02`. Would `02` be converted to `nil` for some reason?  Am I missing something?
[image: PDF part I'm parsing]

```
lines = reader.pages[0].text.split(/\r?\n/)
lines.each_with_index do |line, index|
  values_to_insert = []
  if line.include? "Legal Name:"
    name_line = line.split(":")
    values_to_insert.push(name_line[1])
  end
  if line.include? "Active/Pending Insurance"
    topLine = lines[index+2].split(" ")
    middleLine = lines[index+5].split(" ")
    insuranceLine = lines[index + 7]
    insurance_line_split = insuranceLine.split(" ")
    insurance_line_split.each_with_index do |word, i|
      if word.include? "Insurance"
        values_to_insert.push(insuranceLine.split(":")[1])
      end
    end
    topLine.each_with_index do |word, i|
      if word.include? "Posted"
        values_to_insert.push(topLine[i + 2])
      end
    end
    middleLine.each_with_index do |word, i|
      if word.include? "Effective" or word.include? "Cancellation"
        #puts middleLine[0]
        puts middleLine[1]
        #puts middleLine[i + 1].split(":")[1]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is what happens when I print all lines:

```
Active/Pending Insurance:

   Form:  91X               Type: BIPD/Primary                Posted Date: 02/11
/2015

   Policy/Surety Number:A 3491819            Coverage From:                $0
To:       $1,000,000
   Effective Date:/05/2015                 Cancellation Date:

  Insurance Carrier: PROGRESSIVE EXPRESS INSURANCE COMPANY

         Attn: CUSTOMER SERVICE
     Address:  P. O. BOX 94739
               CLEVELAND, OH 44101 US

    Telephone: (800) 444 - 4487   Fax: (440) 603 - 4555
```

Edited to show the code and even add a picture.  I'm splitting by lines and then splitting again on colons and sometimes spaces.  It's not amazingly clean but I don't think there's a much better way.

Comment: The first place you are going wrong is thinking that you can (in a generalized way) edit a PDF file like you are doing. A PDF file depends heavily on many things not the least of which are byte offsets from one part to the other. It is not designed as an editable format for you to do what you wish with and think it will work.

Comment: @KevinBrown The OP probably does not intend to edit a PDF file, but only extract information from it.

Comment: @KevinBrown yes, it's what sawa said.  I am not editting, only parsing.

Comment: @iain I've edited to show the code.  I don't know that it will help much but it was my fault for not including it originally.

Comment: So if you look at the value of lines .... print them out ... does that line that you "think" has the date in it have it? By looking at the image, it appears that the date is slightly offset from the line of text that is the label. Enough so that the application parsing the text may not consider them to be in the same line. Afterall, it is only attempting to do exactly that because they could be in completely separate structures in completely different objects in the pdf (in fact guaranteed because they are in different fonts)..

Comment: You might try, as a test, searching each line for the `02` and then pulling out all the stuff around it to check you're parsing what you think you're parsing. If the `02` isn't found at all then you know the parser hasn't found it for some reason, and then you can try something else, perhaps converting the pdf to a text document and then parsing that.

Comment: @iain When I print out all the lines it doesn't show an `02`.  I've added this to my question.  I didn't realize there was a way to convert a pdf to text.  Do you have a gem suggestion?

Comment: @KevinBrown Good suggestion, but when I print out all lines, the 02 isn't shown there.  It's likely that the parse isn't picking it up for some reason.  I've edited my question to show all lines printed out.

Comment: Nope, see the one above it. Policy/Insurity number is also missing the first letter. So those are missing .. but why. Ask the company providing the software that is parsing the text. Is it your code or some library?

Comment: Please share the PDF in question for analysis.

Comment: @KevinBrown Sure enough!  Hmm, maybe the library (https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader) is missing it?

Comment: @mkl This one (click the report button).  http://li-public.fmcsa.dot.gov/LIVIEW/pkg_carrquery.prc_carrlist?n_dotno=2575184&s_prefix=MC&n_docketno=&s_legalname=&s_dbaname=&s_state=

Comment: Not only the "02" is missing, also the "C" of the Policy/Surety Number.

Comment: @mkl Yes, as KevinBrown has mentioned, something (likely the pdf-reader library) is not reading it correctly.

Comment: Oh , indeed, he did. Ok, I've looked into the PDF. There is nothing special about the representation of the missing parts, there are operations `(02/05/2015) Tj` and `(CA 3491819) Tj` drawing them, nothing fancy. The only special thing is that these strings are drawn slightly higher than the preceding respective label. Probably that's why the pdf reader does not consider them parts of the same line as the label while for later characters, farther away from the label, this difference in height is not considered a problem

Comment: @mkl Hmm...so am I out of luck?  If I parse a pdf with the lines on slightly different heights it'll miss some of the characters?

Comment: I've just looked into the ruby code. It first collects all strings drawn, then combines those following each other on exactly the same height. Then it calculates some mean character height and widths and accordingly creates a string array to represent the page lines. Then it iterates over the combined strings and replaces characters in the string array by the respective string. Thus, in case of characters at nearly the same height this process can drop some characters...

Comment: In **page_layout.rb** `col_count` is defined using `@col_count ||= ((@page_width  / @mean_glyph_width) * 1.05).floor`; You might want to try playing around with that *magic number* `1.05`, Maybe for a value of `1.20` you don't have those character drops. The downside: this might introduce additional space characters here and there.

Comment: @mkl You freaking genius.  Tinkering with that number did the trick.  I went with 1.10.  Please feel free to leave that as the answer and I'll HAPPILY accept it!

Comment: That's great, I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem occurs at positions where multiple pieces of text are on the same line but don't use **exactly** the same base line. In case of the PDF at hands,

[image]

(at least) the policy number and the effective date are positioned slightly higher than their respective labels.

The cause for this is the way the [pdf-reader library](http://github.com/yob/pdf-reader) used by the OP brings together the text pieces drawn on the page:

- It determines a number of columns and rows to arrange the letters in and
- creates an array of the rows number of strings filled with the columns number of spaces.
- It then combines consecutive text pieces from the PDF on exactly the same base line and
- finally puts these combined text pieces into the string array starting from the position best matching their starting position in the PDF.

As fonts used in PDFs usually are not monospaced, this procedure can result in overlapping strings, i.e. erasure of one of the two. The step combining strings on the same baseline prevents erasure in that case, but for strings on slightly different base lines, this overlapping effect can still occur.

What one can do, is increase the number of columns used here.

The library in [page_layout.rb](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader/blob/master/lib/pdf/reader/page_layout.rb) defines

```
def col_count
  @col_count ||= ((@page_width  / @mean_glyph_width) * 1.05).floor
end
```

As you see there already is some *magic number* `1.05` in use to slightly increase the number of columns. By increasing this number even more, no erasures as observed by the OP should occur anymore. One should not increase the factor too much, though, because that can introduce unwanted space characters where none belong.

The OP reported that increasing the magic number to `1.10` sufficed in his case.